# CSS Выборка элементов :nth-of-type?

Tags: css, css3, nth-of-type

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать выборку 4-х элементов через 4 элемента?

```css
body{
 margin:0;
  font-size:0;
}

.bl{
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(100vw / 25);
  height:calc(100vw / 25);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid #000;
  font-size:6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bl">1</div>
<div class="bl">2</div>
<div class="bl">3</div>
<div class="bl">4</div>
<div class="bl">5</div>
<div class="bl">6</div>
<div class="bl">7</div>
<div class="bl">8</div>
<div class="bl">9</div>
<div class="bl">10</div>
<div class="bl">11</div>
<div class="bl">12</div>
<div class="bl">13</div>
<div class="bl">14</div>
<div class="bl">15</div>
<div class="bl">16</div>
<div class="bl">17</div>
<div class="bl">18</div>
<div class="bl">19</div>
<div class="bl">20</div>
<div class="bl">21</div>
<div class="bl">22</div>
<div class="bl">23</div>
<div class="bl">24</div>
```

Надо выбрать 5,6,7,8,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пока придумал только так:

```
.bl:nth-child(8n + 5),
.bl:nth-child(8n + 6),
.bl:nth-child(8n + 7),
.bl:nth-child(8n + 8){}
```